# Parser output divergence for almost identical sentences-- why?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Why do I get such different parse trees, when I run these two almost identical sentences through TreeAnnotation? The first one returns correctly "SQ (VBZ Does)..)" pattern, bu the second one shows "S (NP (NNP Does)...". Is this an error? Thanks.

1. Does he have time?
   (ROOT (SQ (VBZ Does) (NP (PRP he)) (VP (VB have) (NP (NN time))) (. ?)))
2. Does John have time?
   (ROOT (S (NP (NNP Does) (NNP John)) (VP (VBP have) (NP (NN time))) (. ?)))

Answer (score 0):

Cute -- this looks like a POS tagging bug. In the first case, "Does" is correctly tagged as VBZ; in the second, it is incorrectly tagged as a proper noun (NNP). Likely, this is the sequence model in the POS tagger messing up: Since both "Does" and "John" are capitalized, it prefers tagging them both as proper nouns.

Comment: That's true-- if I change "Does" to "does", then I get VBZ.... interesting. I guess it's confusing does with a female deer.

Comment: But, here is a puzzler: first letter capitalized or not: "schedule an appointment" gives (ROOT (NP (NP (NN schedule)) (NP (DT an) (NN appointment)))), whereas "Schedule an appointment" produces (ROOT (S (VP (VB Schedule) (NP (DT an) (NN appointment))))). I expected the same output in both cases.